# Import a wallet generated by another website to my node?

Tags: wallet, import

so I have a wallet generated by some other website, I have the address and the privkey.

I want to get that wallet imported & all it's previous transactions into my full node, I am using Bitcoin Core.

How can I do such a thing?

Thanks